# jquery validation-with mvc is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, metadata

I am using jquery vaidation in mvc and it is working every where except in one view which contains other view like so :

```
          <div id="DivBtnAnswer">
          @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AnsComm", new { ProdductID = 
          item.ProductID, CommentID = item.ID }, new AjaxOptions { 
          HttpMethod ="POST", LoadingElementId = "LoadingAns", UpdateTargetId = "DivAns}))
                 {
                    <input type="submit" value="answer" />
                    <div id="DivAns"></div>
                 }
            </div>
```

my create action returns this partial view which where the validation doesn't work :

```
          @model honar.Models.Domain.Tbl_Comments
          @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { Url = 
          "/Home/InsertComment", HttpMethod = "POST", LoadingElementId = 
          "Loading", UpdateTargetId = "Msg" }))
            {@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           <div id="Msg" style=""></div>
           <div class="form-horizontal">
           @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
           @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductID)
           <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label 
         col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>

     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: everything is right but it is not working properly

Comment: no one know.....